# rails 3.2, twitter bootstrap why width of buttons with icons is not correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add an icon next to a button, the icon appears, but, the location is wrong, and the button total width is wrong too, please check the image bellow, I tried to set the width of the red button, but, the icon still appear on the button text.

[image]

here is haml code I've used:

```
= link_to new_class_room_path, {:class=>'btn btn-primary'} do
  %i{:class=>'icon-plus'}
    %span
      New Class Room

%a{:class=>"btn btn-danger", :ref=>"#", :style=>'width: 200px;'}
  %i{:class=>"icon-trash icon-white"}
    Delete
```

Any one can tell me what I am missing here ?
p.s: if I do not use icons, the button will appear normally with correct width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've nested your text inside of your icons.

Instead of:

```
= link_to new_class_room_path, {:class=>'btn btn-primary'} do
  %i{:class=>'icon-plus'}
    %span
      New Class Room

%a{:class=>"btn btn-danger", :ref=>"#", :style=>'width: 200px;'}
  %i{:class=>"icon-trash icon-white"}
    Delete
```

Use:

```
= link_to new_class_room_path, {:class=>'btn btn-primary'} do
  %i{:class=>'icon-plus'}
  %span
    New Class Room

%a{:class=>"btn btn-danger", :ref=>"#", :style=>'width: 200px;'}
  %i{:class=>"icon-trash icon-white"}
  Delete
```